# bootstrap dropdown on mouse over the menu item should show edit/delete icon on right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to include edit,delete icon in bootstrap menu item on mouse over.  and also while click on edit/delete icon, it should call edit/delete method respectively.

Need to achieve this in the below bootstrap dropdown,

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

On mouse over HTML/CSS/JavaScript menu item that should display 'edit/delete' icon nearby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this with CSS but there are several many ways. 
You can call edit or delete functions by adding a click event on `<i>` tag with an appropriate classname.

```
  ul>li>a:hover i{
    display:block !important;
    float:right !important;
  }
  ul>li>a>i{
    display:none !important;
  }
  .glyphicon-edit{
    padding-left:7%;
  }
```

Working jsfiddle:
  https://jsfiddle.net/6v4d7kg9/

Comment: When i introduced event handling for edit/delete/change . creates more problem like at a time edit and change event triggering, if i stopped it is using event.stopPropagation then its is not closing dropdown.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844709/bootstrap-dropdown-on-mouse-over-the-menu-item-event-handling-stops-dropdown-clo