# bootstrap dropdown on mouse over the menu item event handling stops dropdown closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fiddle link to play : https://jsfiddle.net/kumkanillam/6v4d7kg9/1/

My requirement is, change,edit,remove event should be fired separately and icon alignment in right side not in bottom and dropdown should be closed after event handling done.

#### html

Below button alignment is correct, but it is triggering two events.(ie., if i clicked edit icon then it is triggering edit() and change())

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Inside Anchor Tag
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" onclick="change()">HTML<i onclick="edit()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><i onclick="remove()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="change()">CSS<i onclick="edit()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><i onclick="remove()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="change()">JavaScript<i onclick="edit()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><i onclick="remove()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
  <br />
```

Below button works perfectly, but alignment is not in right side

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Outside Anchor Tag
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" onclick="change()">HTML</a><i onclick="edit()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><i onclick="remove()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="change()">CSS</a><i onclick="edit()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><i onclick="remove()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="change()">JavaScript</a> <i onclick="edit()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><i onclick="remove()"class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
```

#### Javascript

```
function change(){        
    console.log('change');
}
function edit(){
    //i tried event.stopPropagation() - thats leaving me to close dropdown.
    console.log('edit');
}
function remove(){
    console.log('remove');
}
```

#### CSS

```
ul>li>a:hover i{
 display:block !important;
 float:right !important;
}
ul>li>a>i{
 display:none !important;
}
.glyphicon-edit{
padding-left:7%;
}

ul>li:hover i{
 display:block !important;
 float:right !important;
}
ul>li>i{
 display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Icons are aligning in right side.\

Comment: @BlackBird my problem is,  'inside anchor tag' button alignment is ok but when i click on the edit/remove then change event too triggering . that should be stopped. If I stopped using event.stopPropagation then it's not closing dropdown.

Comment: Why would you want to put the icons outside of the anchor tag if you plan on them showing up on it's right side?

Comment: I want to put it in inside anchor tag.. If i placed it inside of anchor tag, then onclick of edit icon triggers and also change() method too triggered. ..

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `e.cancelBubble = true;` instead of `e.stopPropogation()` since it is a jquery event generated function. Force manual toggle of dropdown to open and close onclick. Use bootstrap class `pull-right` to right align the glyphicons

**JS**

```
function change(){

   console.log('change');
}
function edit(e){
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp("fast");
    console.log('edit');
}
function remove(e){
console.log('here remo');
     e.cancelBubble = true;
   $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp("fast");
    console.log('remove');
}
$(function(){
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
console.log("here");
     $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
});

})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6v4d7kg9/4/)**

Comment: if we cancelled bubbling then it will not close dropdown. ( since we stopped event bubbling).

Comment: @kumkanillam do you wanna close the dropdown once you click on any event

Comment: yes.  I required default behavior of bootstrap drop down. since that will take care of outside click closing too.

Comment: @kumkanillam I would recommend to remove the <i> tags form the anchor tag and put them in span in the same list element.

Comment: there comes alignment problem. some how i fixed it in hard way.https://jsfiddle.net/kumkanillam/6v4d7kg9/6/  Please verify is it the correct approach or anything do I need to alter....

Comment: Yes it is a decent approach

Comment: on clicking outside drop down should close it. that is behavior in bootstrap dropdown i would love to have

Comment: refer this for the above behaviuor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561315/hide-the-drop-down-menu-when-clicking-outside/38561407#38561407

Comment: Why not use `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @LuukSkeur I dont know how will it stop the action from propogating to the parent component